# how to mutate for grouped table

Tags: r, dplyr

i have 'abc' table like this,

```
> abc
country   date      count
A      2020-03-01     1
A      2020-03-02     2
A      2020-03-03     3
B      2020-03-01     2
B      2020-03-02     5
B      2020-03-03     10
C      2020-03-01     1
C      2020-03-02     3
C      2020-03-03     6
```

and I want to mutate 'abc' table with 'rate' that meaning "x-day's count/(x-1)-day's count".

like this.

```
> abc
country   date      count  rate
A      2020-03-01     1     NA
A      2020-03-02     2     2
A      2020-03-03     3     1.5
B      2020-03-01     2     NA
B      2020-03-02     5     2.5
B      2020-03-03     10    2
C      2020-03-01     1     NA
C      2020-03-02     3     3
C      2020-03-03     6     2
```

how can i make it?

waiting for your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
abc %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(rate = count/lag(count))

#  country date       count  rate
#  <fct>   <fct>      <int> <dbl>
#1 A       2020-03-01     1  NA  
#2 A       2020-03-02     2   2  
#3 A       2020-03-03     3   1.5
#4 B       2020-03-01     2  NA  
#5 B       2020-03-02     5   2.5
#6 B       2020-03-03    10   2  
#7 C       2020-03-01     1  NA  
#8 C       2020-03-02     3   3  
#9 C       2020-03-03     6   2
```

`shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(abc)[, rate := count/shift(count), country]
```

Or `head`/`tail` in base R to do this.

```
abc$rate <- with(abc, ave(count, country, FUN = function(x) 
                 c(NA, tail(x, -1)/head(x, -1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
abc %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   mutate(rate = c(NA, count[-n()]/count[-1]))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(abc)[, rate := c(NA, count[.N]/count[-1]), country]
```

Comment: it is working! but it has to change the numerator and denominator. anyway thank you :)